# Blank touch screen after upgrade to Bullseye

Tags: touchscreen, raspberry-pi-os, pi-b+

I have for many years been using the official Raspberry Pi touchscreen with a Model B+ Pi. I recently upgraded the OS to Bullseye and the touch screen no longer displays anything.

When I boot the Pi I get the initial rainbow screen then the splash screen and then a blank screen. The screen is dimply lit, not black, but shows nothing more. I have tried a number of things from upgrading firmware to reminaging the SD card but nothing seems to work.

The Pi works fine when plugged into a normal HDMI monitor.

My system is as follows.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/C $ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS    : 697.95
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : 0010
Serial      : 000000004fee21e5
Model       : Raspberry Pi Model B Plus Rev 1.2

pi@raspberrypi:~/C $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.81+ #1490 Mon Nov 22 14:02:22 GMT 2021 armv6l GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi:~/C $ cat /etc/debian_version 
11.1

pi@raspberrypi:~/C $ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@raspberrypi:~/C $
```

Comment: " I recently upgraded the OS to Bullseye" DESPITE the official recommendation. "Linux raspberrypi 5.10.81+" an experimental kernel. Do a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be resolved as a work around with the following line placed in /boot/config.txt

```
dtparam=i2c_vc_baudrate=50000
```

It is on ongoing issue with the Pi in general.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4686

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

Edit /boot/config.txt.

In [pi4] section, comment out the dtoverlay statement thus:

```
[pi4]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Then uncomment the corresponding line in the [all] section below:

```
[all]
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```